# How to map files in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 9.

I first opened up a scala project and when clicking on a .scala file it asked how I wanted the .scala file treated?

I said as a text file.

Now I installed the scala plugin, and it seems to have kept the .scala mapped to a text file (when it renders the code for a .scala file, it looks like a text file, no syntax highlighting etc).

How can I fix this?

Comment: The first step is probably to upgrade IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: Right, IntelliJ 11.0.1 is the latest.

Comment: yes but I don't want to pay $$ at the moment, I have a licensed copy of 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at File Types under Settings.

I have IntelliJ 11.0.1.  I don't see a Scala binding.

Comment: my registered patterns for scala is empty also. ok so I had to remove the .scala pattern for text file mappings, thanks1